# How to screenshot specific elements from PDF textbook?

Tags: python, ocr, screenshot

I am wanting to take a screenshot of all the "Theorem" boxes in my math textbook and store them in my OneNote so that I have a quick reference of important theorems.

An example theorem is shown in the attached picture. They all have red headers, and yellow-ish backgrounds.

[Example of Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiwPj.png)

I have a python code that somewhat worked, but it only screenshotted the word "Theorem" and not the entire theorem. The partial grab is shown here:

[partial grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1eo3.png)

This code is not great, so any ideas how I can make it grab the entire theorem? I tried making a bigger bounding box, but since each theorem is different in size, that didn't work well.

Also, don't need to have the code auto populate my OneNote if not possible. Saving screenshots to a folder is fine.

Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import re
from PIL import Image

# Define the PDF file path
pdf_file = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Textbook\MathTextbookPDF.pdf'

# Define the folder to save screenshots
output_folder = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Theorems'

# Create the output folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
    os.makedirs(output_folder)

# Open the PDF file using PyMuPDF
pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_file)

# Define a regular expression to match "Theorem"
theorem_pattern = r'Theorem'

# Define the range of pages you want to process
start_page = 100
end_page = 200

# Set the DPI (dots per inch) for the screenshot
dpi = 500  # Adjust this value as needed

# Iterate through the specified range of pages
for page_number in range(start_page - 1, end_page):
    # Extract text from the page
    page = pdf_document[page_number]
    text = page.get_text()

    # Check if the page contains a theorem
    if re.search(theorem_pattern, text):
        # Find the coordinates of the text instances containing "Theorem"
        text_instances = page.search_for(theorem_pattern)

        # Iterate through text instances and capture regions
        for instance in text_instances:
            # Define the coordinates of the region to capture with a larger bounding box
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = instance
            # Expand the bounding box to capture a larger region 
            x0 -= 20
            y0 -= 20
            x1 += 20
            y1 += 20

            # Convert the page to an image with the specified DPI
            image = page.get_pixmap(matrix=fitz.Matrix(dpi / 72, dpi / 72), clip=(x0, y0, x1, y1))

            # Create a PIL image from the PyMuPDF image
            pil_image = Image.frombytes("RGB", [image.width, image.height], image.samples)

            # Check if any pixel in the captured region matches the desired background colors
            background_colors = set(pil_image.getdata())
            desired_background_colors = {(242, 90, 82), (254, 234, 215)}  # Adjust these values as needed

            if any(color in desired_background_colors for color in background_colors):
                # Save the image to the output folder
                screenshot_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f'page_{page_number + 1}_theorem.png')
                pil_image.save(screenshot_path, 'PNG')

# Close the PDF document
pdf_document.close()
```

Edit:
Pictures of a couple of entire pages from the PDF.

[image: Full Page 2]
[image: Full Page 1]

Comment: Please add a sample of two pages in PDF format or a link to the file to the question.

Comment: Edited the original post and added the pictures. As can be seen, each theorem box is different in size, but consistent in format.